# How to the get the correct value in drop down list during editing in codeiginiter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-table

My Problem is, I am saving one text field in the dropdown form.
During Editing, the exact value is not displaying in that text field area.

[image]

The first picture shows that I save the Praveen Kumar accounts and aravinth using droplist form...[image]

the second pictures show, during editing I cannot retrieve the second name properly...

```
 <?php foreach ($s as $r): ?>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><a href='javascript:void(0);'  class='remove'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
        <td><select style="width:200px" class="form-control input-xs"   data-width="100%"name="Tname[]">

<?php foreach ($query as $row ): ?>    

<option value="<?=$row['name']?>"><?=$row['name']?></option> 
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </select></td>
    <td><input style="width:80px" type="text" name="TAmount[]" class="form-control input-xs price" value="<?=$r['TAmount'];?>"></td>
   <td ><input style="width:50px" type="text" name="Per[]" id="amount" class="form-control input-xs amount" value="<?=$r['Per'];?>"></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" id="addMore" title="Add More Person"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></td>
  </tr><?php endforeach ?>
```

This is table code for editing...

[image] this pname is used as a drop down list for that page.
please help me to solve the issues.

Comment: What is your selected dropdown value?

Comment: are you using AJAX to send data to backend PHP code and to store the data in DB?

Comment: that is took from another database@DanishAli

Comment: no i did'nt use ajax for drop down list@HimanshuUpadhyay

Comment: i have edited my question @DanishAli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set your selected value, when you create your `select` options, you should check if the current `option` match the value of your result line `name` or `PName`.

```
<?php foreach ($query as $row ): ?>
    <option value="<?=$row['name']?>" <?php echo ($r['PName'] == $row['name']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?>><?=$row['name']?></option> 
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: undefined PName

Comment: The "name" in your code is the field name of the saved database??

Comment: What does you array `$r` contain ? You need to put the right key, maybe it's `name`. Like you did for `$r['TAmount']`

Comment: $r -> i am fetching the data from the database "tieup details" $row -> is took the name from the database "accmaster" in a dropdown list

Comment: sir your code does not give a error, but i does not working

Comment: Do you test the right key for `$r` ? If it's `$r['name']` have you checked it's value ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184743/discussion-between-teddy-and-nesku).

Comment: i can't understand

Comment: your code is not getting error,but i does not shows an correct value.